# What is the right way to initialize a QList?

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

What is the right way to initialize QList? I want to make this code shorter:

```
QSplitter splitter;
QList<int> list;
list.append(1);
list.append(1);
splitter.setSizes(list);
```

But when I use initialization from std::list, it doesn't seem be working:

```
splitter.setSizes(QList<int>::fromStdList(std::list<int>(1, 1)));
```

In latter case, the splitter seems to divide in ratio 1:0.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You could use the following code:

```
QList<int> list = QList<int>() << 1 << 1;
```

or initializer list with C++11:

```
QList<int> list({1, 1});
```

You can enable the latter with the -std=c++0x or -std=c++11 option for gcc. You will also need the relevant Qt version for that where initializer list support has been added to the QList constructor.

Comment: Using Qt 5.2 it throws `error: expected expression QList<int> list2({1, 1});`

Comment: @ꜱᴀᴍᴏᴛʜ: you need `CONFIG+=c++11`.

Comment: What is that `()` in `list({1,1})`? it give me an syntax error. Should be `QList<int> list {1, 1};`?

Answer (score 4):

Never use the `QList<int>() << 1 << 1;` variant, as it's really slow.
use always the `list({1, 1})` variant.

source: https://www.angrycane.com.br/en/2018/06/19/speeding-up-cornercases/